# How to find that page is loading first time?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a class on div when page loads first time in php. Class is adding in jquery on window load function when class add then there is animation on page. But i need when user visit the page first time only then he can see the animation and after that page does not need to show all animations again. is there any way in php to check that page is loading first time or not. This is my code in jquery.

```
 $(window).load(function(){
     $('.header-div').addClass('animation');

 )};
```

But i want to add 'animation' class in php if page loads first time on header-div. I am trying to doind it with session. But everytime when i refresh the page session id is changed.

```
    if($postid == 4)
     {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();



     }
```

Comment: First time ever or during the session?

Comment: first time when user close thebrowser  window and again visit the website then again he can see the animation.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, you can use a `sessionStorage` to find out if the page has been visited.  The `sessionStorage` are built-in in most modern browsers I can be used easily:

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('visited')) {
    $('.header-div').addClass('animation');
    sessionStorage.setItem('visited', true);
}
```

The `sessionStorage` is a good choice for what you want to do since the value will be stored per domain and it will be dropped automatically when the tab will be closed.

I didn't use php for awhile but I guess you may also set a session variable on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you want the animation to show only the first time a unique user visits the page? In that case, you'll want to save a cookie on the user's computer and check for that cookie before adding the animation class to the header div.

Comment: I am using this jquery to check if page is visited or not. $(document).ready(function(){
     if($.cookie("firsttime") != 1)
   {
    $.cookie("firsttime", "1");
    //alert("fghfghf");
   }else{
    
    //alert("second time");
   }
  
  
 });    but animation class is already loading with jquery. so i need to add this class in php if user visit the page first time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be setting the session id every time.

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
/*Check to see if $_SESSION['visited'] has already been set during this users visit.
Store the result of that check in to the variable $visited.
*/
$visited = isset($_SESSION['visited']);
/* Set $_SESSION['visited'] so that the above check will return true on future visits. */
$_SESSION['visited'] = true;
/* With the snippet inside the html tag, we're echoing "first-visit" 
as a class name if $visited is equal to false, and echoing 
nothing if it's equal to true. */
?>
<div class="header-div <?=$visited?'':'first-visit'?>">
...
</div>
```

Then in your js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.first-visit').addClass('animation');
});
```

For your specific case, you may want to add some more logic to check if the $postid==4 first, as you did in your question.